# Transferring simple values to readable HighChart data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have one simple question concerning HighCharts data values.
I took simple values from the html textarea with this code:

```
  $.valHooks.textarea = {
     get: function (elem) {
         return elem.value.replace(/\r?\n/g, "\r\n");
     }
 };
 var sample = {};
 sample.data = $('textarea').val();
 sample.data = sample.data.split(","); //transferring to array
```

And now I want those values to be read as HighChart data in this format for example:

```
series: [{
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, ...]
   },
```

How can I achieve that? Is there a method for transferring those values from textarea to readable Highcharts data?
Thanks

Comment: In `sample.data` you have array of strings, while should be array of numbers. In Javascript, use `parseFloat(value)` to parse strings to numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you have not

```
data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, ...]
```

but

```
data: ["7.0", "6.9", "9.5", ...]
```

You need to parse each data's string to number, by parseFloat() function.